# Can Drupal 7 auto unpublish content after a custom content type date has passed?

Tags: drupal-7, content-type

I want Drupal 7 to automatically unpublish content after a given custom content type date has passed. Any ideas/thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules).
And if you want your users / content submitters to schedule the expiration time, perhaps look at the [Schedule module](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler).

Comment: I checked it out, but I can't figure out how to make it work with a custom date field.

Answer (score 1):

[Auto Expire](http://drupal.org/project/auto_expire)
i think this module fulfills your requirements

Comment: That's close. I would like it to expire on a date that's specified in a custom content type that's a date (timestamp).

Comment: so i think Scheduler http://drupal.org/project/scheduler does that job.

Comment: Does anyone know of an example on how this works? Scheduler always errors for me when I try to add an action.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom module (small one) with just a hook_cron(). Have the function retrieve all the nodes, examine the expire date, and if expired, set the status to 0. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7.

I don't have time to write it but here's the general idea for the module:

```
function MYMOUDULE_cron() {
  // db_query to select all nodes with 
  // your date field and status = 1 (published)
  // loop through the $result, performing node_load as applicable, modify the 
  // $node obj with status = 0 | 1 depending upon
  // the date. Then node_save() the $node obj.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that I am using to unpublish content after the expiry date has passed:

```
UPDATE node n
INNER JOIN field_data_field_expiry_date e ON e.entity_id = n.nid
SET n.`status` = 0
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(e.field_expiry_date_value, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%S') < NOW() AND n.`status` = 1
```

As it's all in one query is nice and fast to run.